# MATLAB function that computes $A^n$, being $A$ an square matrix and $n$ an natural number?

Tags: matrices, matlab

Do any of you know a matlab function that computes $A^n$ just like in the following example?

[image]

This question arises in response of discrete time state space systems.

Comment: Do you mean a Matlab function that would give you the "Answer" decomposition ? Definitely not, even using symbolic variables. You have to roll up your sleeves...

Comment: @JeanMarie actually Matlab offers also a symbolic toolbox :)

Comment: @user190080 Yes, it is thinking to Matlab symbolic toolbox that I wrote my remark :):):) I just said that it is impossible to get at once, the "Answer", using symbolic toolbox or not (because **in this case**, a general variable $n$ cannot be "understood" by symbolic tools). One has to decompose into $A^n = P D^n P^{-1}$

Comment: @JeanMarie ah ok, I guess I misunderstood you there. I thought this would be possible, at least in Mathematica it works right out of the box

Comment: @user190080 can I do power ^n of a symbolic matrix in mathematica? I will start to learn how to use this software very soon.

Comment: @gustavoreche yes, no problem at all, it will give you the exact same result as stated in the question - check it out at wolframalpha if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
syms n;
A = sym([0 1; -1/6 5/6]);
[V,D] = eig(A);
An = V*(D^n)*inv(V);
pretty(An);
```

Comment: I learned that the command "pretty" (that I didn't met) makes indeed a pretty work...

Comment: this code only works if the matrix has a basis of eigenvectors... and now I have to seek for a code that computes the generalized eigenvectors of a matrix.

Comment: substituing the lines `[V,D] = eig(A);
An = V*(D^n)*inv(V);` to `[V,J]=jordan(A);
An = V*(J^n)*inv(V)` solved the  ''lack of basis'' problem, because now I have generalized eigenvectors. But the code is not computing the power n of a the matrix, since the J is not an diagonal matrix. So, the problem is half solved, haha.